# Whitelisting domains - handling trailing slashes in the URL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps API key on which I have restrictions set to HTTP application referrers.

[image]

Ideally I would like to whitelist anything on my localhost site.

I have whitelisted `*://localhost:9000/*` which I expected to whitelist all pages.

[image]

I can use my API key on `http://localhost:9000/branches`

I CANNOT use my API key on `http://localhost:9000/branches/` (note the trailing slash).

What is the best way to handle this? Must I explicitly set `*://localhost:9000/*/*` as the whitelisting item? Or is there a better way that accounts for all levels of nesting?

Answer (score 0):

To allow all domain paths from localhost for port 9000 only, add this referrer:

`http://localhost:9000/*`

But make sure you don't use this API key in production or otherwise share it publicly, because that would let other people use your API key from their own localhost:9000.

Hope this helps!